# convert ZipOutputStream into ZipInputStream using PipedStream in java

Tags: zipstream

i want to convert a ZipOutputStream into ZipInputStream using PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream. I am receiving ZipOutputStream from DataHandler, and i don't want to write it on file and then open and read it, rather i want to convert this ZipOutputStream into ZipInputStream for my further processing, like extracting ZipEntry and save it in some file.

```
public String documentReceived(@WebParam(name = "document")final DataHandler dataHandler) {
...
   ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(dataHandler.getOutputStream());

   final PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
   final PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);

   ??? need help here to convert a ZipOutputStream into
   ??? ZipInputStream

...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated... thanks

Comment: What do you even need ```dataHandler``` for, if you don't want to write to the file? You should be able to just pass ```pout``` to new ZipOutputStream, and pass ```pin``` to new ZipInputStream if i understand this right.